# Should the `isLoading` state be in Redux? But what if there can be multiple components that loads data?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

One way we can do in React / Redux is to have the `isLoading` state in Redux (that cause a message "Loading..." or local spinning wheel to show). But what if

1. There can be 5 or 6 components on the page, each with a button that can load data local to that component? Then we don't want the "Loading..." message to be showing for all 5 or 6 components.  Then using all different flags of `isPostDataLoading`, `isVideoDataLoading` can be a lot of flags.
2. If we just have one component but we want to render it 3 times on the page, and it can pull "Info 1", "Info 2", "Info 20"... by a select box, then the `isLoading` will cause all 3 components to be showing the same message in all 3 boxes. (but user is changing the select box in component 2 to load data there).

If we use the component state, it seems class component can work. If it is function component and redux-thunk, when we dispatch a function, somehow we have be to able to use the `setIsLoading()` hook and I am not sure if that's possible.

Comment: Ask yourself: "if I had to take a snapshot of this component right now, for rebuilding later, is this value necessary?". Whether or not the component is loading data is not actually part of its static state, it's a runtime side effect of starting the component with a state that informs the component to start requesting the data that it needs. It's a derived value, and can be set as component state value _at runtime_ based on whether or not there's data, but has no meaning except during runtime.

Comment: it seems like it is only a runtime state... although can you say, even the data for user 1 or 2 is also just runtime state. But let's say we make it a component state, can we make it function component state, because we can't have a `useState()` and be able to use it in `mapDispatchToProps`... I suppose the click handler can `setIsLoading()` first and then invoke `props.loadData()` though...

Comment: classic "redux multiple counters" problem?